# Ingress fake SSL certifikate

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I just re-installed a service (gitlab) on a standard GKE cluster and is now getting an error, when visiting the website:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Subject: Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
Issuer: Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your question is about GitLab (and potentially the Ingress controller it uses which does not appear to be GKE's own Ingress –it's probably nginx-ingress). GKE ingress will not create a fake TLS certificate for you.

Comment: Ah I guess Gitlab's Ingress controller was not removed and that might be the problem